# Control variables in interaction effects

Tags: regression, interaction, controlling-for-a-variable

I'm new to econometrics and this might be a dumb question.. but if I were to include an interaction term, do I also have to input the variables separately as a control variable?
For example, Y = a + beta1 + beta2 + beta1*beta2. This contains all of the variables separately as a control. Is this always the right way to go? I used to think it is, but sometimes, I get confused because some papers have a model like Y = a + beta1 + beta1*beta2. Is this bad practice?
When would some one include all of the variables separately as controls and not for others?

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=interaction+include+variable